# gmap api 3.0: "mouseover" event on overlay returns "undefined" event in listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I'm working on a implementation of Google Maps 3.0 with one project and I'm using jquery-gmap3 plugin to control the map. Everything is fine, just IE9 (as usually) has some problems with proper interpretation of the page.

I have a jquery-gmap3 clustered markers (which is, I assume, represented as an overlay and not a marker) and I have a text in it - a count of markers contained in this cluster. Then, I have a `mouseover` and `mouseout` events attached to this cluster by usual means:

```
cluster: { 
  events: { 
    mouseover: function(c, e, d) {...}, 
    mouseout: function(c, e, d) {...} 
  } 
}
```

My basic problem is, there is no event `(typeof e == 'undefined')` provided in event listener handler function, when I move to or from the cluster overlay.

I've tracked down the problem to this method in `jquery-gmap3.js`:

```
// (that `console.log` was added by me)
this._attachEvent = function(sender, name, fnc, data, once){
  google.maps.event['addListener'+(once?'Once':'')](sender, name, function(event) {
    console.log([sender, name, event, data, once]);
    fnc.apply($this, [sender, event, data]);
  });
}
```

As it seems, it is registering events with Google API and then forwards it to my custom handler. Which would be fine, but it seems, Google API itself is NOT returning that event in the first place, which - according to Google documentation, it should.

My question is then, whether someone has experienced similar behavior before and could provide some insight.

PS: WHY do I want it? IE9 triggers `mouseout` event, when I move cursor over the text (count of the markers). I suppose, playing with event propagation would be sufficient to correct this behavior. Or do you have any thoughts about this topic as well?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: I'd suggest either filing a bug against the google maps api for the specific problem: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list or posting a link to a page that demonstrates the issue so people can test against it/verify.